# Javafx Table stops responding to binding updates

Tags: java, javafx

I have the following callback for a column in a JavaFx `TableView`

```
public class CuePreWaitCallback implements Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<cObj,String>, ObservableValue<String>> {

    @Override
    public ObservableValue<String> call(final CellDataFeatures<cObj, String> param) {
        final Timeline preWait = param.getValue().getCTimeline().getPreWait();
        return new StringBinding() {
            {
                super.bind(param.getValue().getCTimeline().getPreWait().playhead());
                super.bind(param.getValue().getCTimeline().getPreWait().waitTime());
            }

            @Override
            protected String computeValue() {
                System.out.println("Value Called---------------------------------------------->");
                return preWait.getAbsoluteDuration().subtract(preWait.getPlayhead()).toString();
            }
        };
    }

}
```

Notice the giant print statement in the middle. All of the sudden, the GUI stops updating when the values change. Note that the values change very rapidly (if that matters). About every 3-5 milliseconds (It's displaying a time).

About the `Timeline` class: The `getAbsoluteDuration()` method returns a `TimeElapsed` object, which subtracts the `preWait.getPlayhead()` `TimeElapsed` object to create a new `TimeElapsed` object of their difference. The `TimeElapsed` `toString()` method is then called.

Comment: What is Timeline? JavaFX's Timeline does not have a getAbsoluteDuration or getPlayhead method. It is possible that those methods could block the UI.

Comment: @assylias I should have made a note. `Timeline` is not the JavaFx Timeline. It's my own class. I would have named it something different, but I started this project before I decided on JavaFx for the GUI.

Comment: Without knowing what these methods in your Timeline class do, it is difficult to say much...